Finding functors $F : \mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf{Set}$ with $F(X) \cong T^X$
For which sets $T$ is there a covariant functor $F : \mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf{Set}$ such that $F(X) \cong T^X$ for every set $X$? (The question is trivial for contravariant functors.)
The question has been motivated by SE/4971114. Here is my progress:
If $T=\emptyset$ is empty, then there is a map $\emptyset \to \{\star\}$ but no map $T^{\emptyset} \to T^{\{\star\}}$, so there cannot be a functor. If $T$ is a singleton, we can take a constant functor. If $T$ has $2$ elements, we have the (covariant) power set functor, mapping $f : X \to Y$ to the direct image $f_* : P(X) \to P(Y)$. If $T$ has $3$ elements, consider the functor $X \mapsto \{(A_0,A_1) : A_0 \subseteq A_1 \subseteq X\}$, again functorial via direct images. This is isomorphic to $\{0,1,2\}^X$ regarding $A_0$ as the preimage of $\{0\}$ and $A_1$ as the preimage of $\{0,1\}$ of a function $X \to \{0,1,2\}$. The same works for every non-empty finite set $T$.
If $T = \mathbb{N}$, I tried to take the functor mapping a set $X$ to the set of sequences $A_0 \subseteq A_1 \subseteq A_2 \subseteq \dotsc$ with $\bigcup_n A_n = X$. If $f : X \to Y$ is a surjective map, then the latter condition is preserved, we also have $\bigcup_n f_*(A_n)=Y$. So indeed there is a functor $F : \mathbf{Set}_{\text{epi}} \to \mathbf{Set}$ with $F(X) \cong \mathbb{N}^X$.
In the general case, if $T$ is any set, we may replace it with an isomorphic set and hence assume that $T$ is an ordinal number $\alpha$. Then we may map $X$ to the set of increasing sequences $(A_i : i < \alpha)$ of subsets of $X$ such that $X = \bigcup_{i < \alpha} A_i$. These sequences correspond to maps $f : X \to \alpha$, namely via $f(x) = \min \{i < \alpha : f(x) \in A_i\}$, and conversely $A_i = \{x \in X : f(x) \leq i\}$. The sequences are functorial in $X$ with respect to surjective maps, again via direct images. So we have a functor $F : \mathbf{Set}_{\text{epi}} \to \mathbf{Set}$ with $F(X) \cong T^X$.
So I still don't know if there is any infinite set $T$ so that a functor can be defined on the whole category $\mathbf{Set}$.

Ah nevermind, it's easy to fix. If $T$ is non-empty, $T$ is isomorphic to a successor ordinal (as a set), so we might as well assume $T = \alpha + 1$ for some ordinal number $\alpha$. Now, as in the finite case, map $X$ to the increasing sequences $(A_i : i < \alpha)$ of subsets of $X$. (We leave out the last index!) This is functorial w.r.t. all maps. The sequences correspond to maps $f : X \to \alpha+1$ via
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \min \{i < \alpha : x \in A_i \} & x \in \bigcup_{i < \alpha} A_i \\ \alpha & \text{else} \end{cases}$$

Instead of thinking in terms of sequences of subsets of $X$, you can just directly say that if $f:X\to Y$, then $f_:T^X\to T^Y$ is defined by $f_(g)(y)=\min{g(x):f(x)=y}$, or $\alpha$ if $y$ is not in the the image of $f$.

@EricWofsey Thanks! This is also a nice description. It works more generally if $T$ is a well-ordered set with a largest element $\infty$. So we don't need ordinals. On the other hand, showing functoriality with your description is a bit less obvious (I had to calculate a few things), whereas functoriality of sequences is trivial.
